# I am trying to have the color of my menu button that was clicked change after the clicked page is loaded, using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have menu include in my header page.

```
menu.html

<div class="menu">
    <a href="index.php" id="index"><strong>Dashboard</strong></a>
    <a href="grades.php"id="grades"><strong>Grades</strong></a>
    <a href="courses.php" id="courses"><strong>Courses</strong></a>
    <a href="inbox.php" id="inbox"><strong>Inbox</strong></a>
</div>
```

This is the css for it.

```
.menu > a{
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 25%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #911600;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
}
```

I want that after the menu button is clicked the color should change. I know that it could be implemented in much easier ways, but I am new to jquery and I want to implemet it using jquery. I tried doing it as follows.

```
app.js

$(".menu a").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

This is the active class.

```
.active{
    background-color: #d1c0a8 !important;
    color: #911600 !important;
}
```

The problem is that it only changes it for a second because after applying the active class it loads the link, which reloads the original menu. I tried preventing this from happening by using `e.preventDefault()` and loading the page manually and then changing the style as follows.

```
app.js

$(".menu a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    window.open(url, "_self");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

But it doesn't work. How could I make it work?

Comment: One way to do this would be to send a GET parameter with the url that's loading and on page load, apply classes based on the GET params.

Comment: Once the page reloads, all jQuery must reload. You can try adding something to the query string in the url or passing a variable from the backend.

Comment: @StaticBeagle I already did it using backend (PHP) I am wondering if it could be done using the frontend

Comment: You can try this code document.ready/onload `$('.menu a').filter(function(){  return window.location.href.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) > -1;  }).addClass('active')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you can sniff for the page URL on page load and activate the correct nav item. Note I hardcoded a url for demo purposes. You would use the commented out part for your site

```js
let url = 'http://website.com/grades.php'; 
// let url = window.location.pathname

let href = url.split("/").reverse()[0]
if (!href) href = "index.php"
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(`.menu a[href="${href}"]`).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.menu>a {
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #911600;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;
}

.active {
  background-color: #d1c0a8 !important;
  color: #911600 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <a href="index.php" id="index"><strong>Dashboard</strong></a>
  <a href="grades.php" id="grades"><strong>Grades</strong></a>
  <a href="courses.php" id="courses"><strong>Courses</strong></a>
  <a href="inbox.php" id="inbox"><strong>Inbox</strong></a>
</div>
```

Comment: To make it a little easier you could use "let url  = window.location.pathname;"                   "let hfer = url.split("/").reverse()[0]".